# After mounting with curlftpfs directory is empty

Tags: mount, ftp

I'd like to mount a directory from a windows server with curlftpfs, but after mounting it I get an empty directory.

When I simply ftp it works, I see the files. Trying with root for now, setting permissions later.

Software versions: curlftpfs 0.9.2 libcurl/7.64.0 fuse/2.9

Have you got any idea what can cause this?

```
root@debian:/home/noocx# curlftpfs foo:bar@baz/www /home/noocx/workspace/remote/baz -v
* Expire in 0 ms for 6 (transfer 0x55d6e792ffa0)
* Expire in 1 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55d6e792ffa0)
...
* Expire in 13 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55d6e792ffa0)
*   Trying x.x.x.x...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Expire in 200 ms for 4 (transfer 0x55d6e792ffa0)
* Connected to baz (x.x.x.x) port 21 (#0)
< 220 Microsoft FTP Service
> USER foo
< 331 Password required
> PASS bar
< 230-Directory has 4,776,472,576 bytes of disk space available.
< 230 User logged in.
> PWD
< 257 "/" is current directory.
* Entry path is '/'
> CWD www
* ftp_perform ends with SECONDARY: 0
< 250 CWD command successful.
* Remembering we are in dir "www/"
* Connection #0 to host baz left intact
```

**UPDATE:**

As I see in curlftpfs debug mode, the data connection is there, file/directory creation works, but I don't get any files/dirs when I do ls -la in the mounted directory. When I check the files with ftp client, they are in the directory.

```
* Re-using existing connection! (#1) with host x.y.z
* Connected to x.y.z (x.x.x.x) port 21 (#1)
* Request has same path as previous transfer
> PASV
* Connect data stream passively
* ftp_perform ends with SECONDARY: 0
< 227 Entering Passive Mode (x,x,x,x,240,223).
*   Trying x.x.x.x...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Expire in 200 ms for 4 (transfer 0x559a03082000)
* Connecting to x.x.x.x (x.x.x.x) port 61663
* Connected to x.x.x (x.x.x.x) port 21 (#1)
> LIST -a
< 125 Data connection already open; Transfer starting.
* Maxdownload = -1
* Remembering we are in dir ""
< 226-Directory has 4,767,813,632 bytes of disk space available.
< 226 Transfer complete.
* Connection #1 to host x.x.x left intact
   unique: 20, success, outsize: 16
unique: 21, opcode: RELEASEDIR (29), nodeid: 1, insize: 64, pid: 0
   unique: 21, success, outsize: 16
```

Comment: I have a note, add `-o utf8` for windows, to avoid trouble with filenames.

Comment: Thanks, adding it.